# Session timeout in laravel 8 + inertia js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, session, inertiajs

Am using laravel 8 and inertia js and I set session_timeout to 10 minutes in .env file.

The problem is after 10 minutes of inactivity when I submit a form i get a model saying 419  | PAGE EXPIRTED. And if i try to visit other pages it works like there is no timeout session

Here is the code of my .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1
```

code in session.php

```
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => true,
```

[image]

How can I redirect user to login page after 10 minutes of inactivity ?

My handler.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to log user out after 10 minutes of inactivity using middleware.

You can find the code here:

https://alfrednutile.info/posts/168/

Answer (score 2):

Go to you **App\Exceptions\Handler** file, and in the render method you could take some action, like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        $response = parent::render($request, $e);
        

        if (!app()->environment('local') && $response->status() == 419){
            
            //Delete the session by force
            $request->session()->flush();

            //Redirects to you login page, asuming this is your component's route
             return Inertia::render('Auth/Login')
        ]);

       /* Handling other exceptions' logic */

}
```

Comment: That did not work + it generates an error when i make cache:clear ``` PHP Fatal error:  Could not check compatibility between App\Exceptions\Handler::render($request, App\Exceptions\Throwable $e)```

Comment: Forget about cleaning the cache, for a moment, the redirection worked?

Comment: i can't even run php artisan serve because of the error

Comment: All right, I need to see 2 things to be able to help you, your original *Handler* file , and the current error log that is throwing.

Comment: I fixed the exception thrown after php artisan serve, turns out I didn't import throwable class, but now instead of 419 error , I get a blank modal

Comment: The blank page was because you have to redirect to you login component, I made that route up.